# Automate GUI testing on Windows of a remote desktop app

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, testing, automation

I am running to a roadblock here, I have to automate some tests for a GUI. The software itself is ran on a remote desktop app, since the application is relatively heavy.

The application itself is sort of a scheduler, for vehicle and employees. which is composed of multiple "sub-programs"

I have tried tools like Autoit, sadly, I cannot read any of the controls on the remote application using the Autoit Windows info. It seems to me that, a GUI on a remote desktop application is unreadable (please correct me if I am wrong!!)

My best bet right now, is an application called SikuliX, an image recognition GUI automation tool based (I think) on Jython. I can use it with Python. But I find this solution a little bit "flimsy". Most of his feature is being able to locate an image based on a rate of similarities, which I find, fantastic.

Since I think I will be going with Python, is there other add-ons that I can also use to enhance my performance, any libraries for mouse control? (PyGUIAuto or PyWinAuto)

If you think that I have a better way to tackle this "remote desktop application GUI automation problem" please let me know! thanks.

Note: The software itself is Java based if this helps.

Comment: If you need to access the controls by text, you have to run an automation script on the same machine with further transferring the data over the network. Please try to use `Inspect.exe` from Windows SDK (just find in Program files) on the server side. Can it recognize the controls and its types/texts?

Comment: And yeah, enable `UIA mode` in `Inspect.exe` if any. The executable can be safely copied from local machine and should work as well.

Comment: Sadly, I do not have access to the other machine, upon opening the remote app, it only shows the application itself as a standalone window, I cannot do anything on the remote PC aside from running the application.

Comment: OK, then only sikuli or its pure Python replacement [lackey](https://github.com/glitchassassin/lackey) would help you though it's not a robust way.

Comment: You can try `Inspect.exe` from local machine just for peace of mind (if you feel lucky), but I don't expect it would work.