# Is it possible to run a test from local to remote (RDP) by Java winAppDriver

Tags: java, selenium, automation, automated-tests, winappdriver

I have learnt about running automation by [Java with winAppDriver.](https://medium.com/software-testing-break-and-improve/tutorial-windows-app-automation-using-winappdriver-and-java-5be661335b25)

I have some pc (WIN 10) that works with RDP, and from some constraints we cannot install nothing on the RDP.

So we want to run the testing from the local for doing automation on the RDP.

By when I'm trying to `inspect.exe` the inner elements that inside the RDP nothing shown.

**So it's not possible ?**

Is it possible by other tools?

Comment: Seems that the answer is NOT

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853973/automate-gui-testing-on-windows-of-a-remote-desktop-app

Answer (score 1):

Inspect.exe is application for local use only. So if you want to inspect something in remote desktop run it's there.

Moreover inspect.exe seems to work fine if you simply copy (without installing whole windows sdk which provides this tool) to the needed pc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).